# How to pass the redirection char ("<" and ">") to a command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a script I'm running to be more readable. I have multiple commands which I would like to separate from the actual output.

My first thought was to use set -x, but this was still lost between the output of the actual commands. So I've found and applied two bash functions which I call before each function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function c_echo(){
    local color=$1;
    shift
    local exp=$@;
    if ! [[ $color =~ '^[0-9]$' ]] ; then
       case $(echo $color | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in
        black) color=0 ;;
        red) color=1 ;;
        green) color=2 ;;
        yellow) color=3 ;;
        blue) color=4 ;;
        magenta) color=5 ;;
        cyan) color=6 ;;
        white|*) color=7 ;; # white or invalid color
       esac
    fi
    tput setaf $color;
    echo $exp;
    tput sgr0;
}

function script_cmd() {
    c_echo YELLOW "\$ $@";
    "$@";
}

export -f script_cmd
export -f c_echo
```

Later inside my script:

```
c_echo GREEN "1. Download insulin (2HIU) and Leucine zipper (2ZTA)."

script_cmd wget https://files.rcsb.org/view/2HIU.cif
```

This works perfectly, but fails on commands which actually do redirection. Is there a way I can work around this?

```
script_cmd charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the colorful output to *stderr*:

```
function script_cmd() {
    c_echo YELLOW "\$ $@" >&2
    #                     ^^^
    "$@";
}
```

If you want to colorize the whole `charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out` command you can

```
script_cmd bash -c 'charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out'
```

or

```
function script_cmd() {
    c_echo YELLOW "\$ $@" >&2
    #                     ^^^
    eval "$@";
    #^^^
}

script_cmd 'charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out'
```

Comment: but I also have to pipe the input command too right? I think that is what's missing

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean. what do u mean by "pipe the input command"?

Comment: do u mean you want to colorize the whole string of `"charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out"`?

Comment: well I want to print out the whole command, and run the command correctly. Not sure if running `script_cmd cat < "asdf"` will work

Comment: is "charmm < setup_2zta.inp > setup_2zta.out" the whole command?

Comment: ok, I checked, and the pipe is redirected correctly to the command, but it's just not being printed correctly

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340129/test-stdout-and-stderr-redirection-in-bash-script

Comment: updated the answer. and yes `[ -t 1 ]` is the correct way to disable color when outputting non-tty files.